# Ember action or this.get works only once

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have this index controller.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        reload() {
            console.log('click on button reload');
            this.get('doReload');
        }
    },
    doReload: Ember.computed(function() {
        console.log('do reload method');
        // ajax action will be here.
    }),
});
```

And this is button in the template.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" {{action 'reload'}}>Reload</button>
```

When I click on the button for the first time, `console.log()` contain 2 line of messages correctly.

> click on button reload
>   do reload method

But when I click on the button for second time or more, `console.log()` contain contain only one line. It doesn't call `doReload` again.

> click on button reload

How to make this.get work every time I click on the action button?

Comment: I'd suggest re-reading the parts of the Ember docs about computed functions. They are pretty clearly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

computed properties are cached until dependent properties are changed.  If you want to just execute a function not inside the action just create and call a function.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        reload() {
            console.log('click on button reload');
            this.doReload();
        }
    },
    doReload: function() {
        console.log('do reload method');
        // ajax action will be here.
    },
});
```